# MotoG won't proceed after Blue M Screen after Cache Wipe& Factory Reset

Tags: boot, fastboot, motorola-moto-g, motorola

Ive been using this MotoG for 2 years now. 
Recently, all the Apps started to Crash on opening and on Restarting the Phone it would always show the "**Optimizing xx Apps of xx**" .I then did a **factory reset** through Settings.

The App crashing problem still persisted after i installed Snapchat,Facebook,WhatsApp. SO i fastbooted the phone and **Wiped Cache** & Did a **factory reset** . After rebooting now, it is stuck on the Blue "M" Screen and would restart to the same if i held the Power Button for 7-10 Seconds.

Please Help.

PS: No Rooting Performed. Phone not under Warranty. Unlock Code:0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out that the phone was locked and nothing else!
Got the unlock code from the Motorola website (Which wasn't working earlier) and unlocked the phone via mfastboot , then reloaded the stock firmware and the phone is good as new!
Unlock Code:3